# hieroglf vs T1 fontenc

Tags: errors, input-encodings

Consider the following MWE (which works)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% works
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
% fails
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\begin{document}
\translitpmhg{\HC}
\end{document}
```

Anyone know how to get these tranliterations to work with T1 encoding instead?

We keep getting an error about `\uunder` not being defined, and it *is* only defined for OT1. Any ideas on how to define it for T1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package mostly seems set up to use T1 or OT1 but just defines a couple of special accents for OT1 only, which seems to be a mistake, really. It uses characters 21 and 24 (`\c` and `\u`) which are 8 and 11 in T1 encoding so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% works
%\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
% fails
\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommand{\uunder}{T1}[1]%
  {{\o@lign{\relax#1\crcr\hidewidth\sh@ft{29}%
    \vbox to.2ex{\hbox{\char8}\vss}\hidewidth}}}

\DeclareTextCommand{\cedover}{T1}[1]%
  {#1\ifdim\fontdimen\@ne\font>\z@%
     \kern-.18em
   \else
     \kern-.4em
   \fi
   \raisebox{1.75ex}{\char11}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\begin{document}
\translitpmhg{\HC}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That just saved a students day

Comment: @daleif might be worth pinging the package maintainer.

Comment: oh or is that you now?

Comment: No, I don't know who is maintaining the package. But Peter sometimes answers online.

Comment: I've sent an email to Peter